# I can't acces a database user's password from digitalocean API

Tags: mongodb, passwords, digital-ocean

I'm trying to get the password of the doadmin user of an existing database(mongodb) in digital ocean through it's API, but all normal methods listed in the [digitalocean's API doc](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/databases_get_user) don't work

For example, when I do a GET request to "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/databases" i get all the databases data but the password field empty.
In the docs, they have an example of retrieving a user's data by doing a GET request to /v2/databases/$DATABASE_ID/users/$USERNAME, with the expected response of:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "app-01",                //all of this is example data
        "role": "normal",
        "password": "jge5lfxtzhx42iff"
    }
}
```

but when I do the request I get:

```
{
    user: { 
        name: 'doadmin', 
        role: 'primary' 
    } 
}
```

I searched in Google and the only thing I can find is guidance in getting the data via its frontend or cli, help please.